# Xamarin android oxyplot having issues with device rotating and axis

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, oxyplot

I am new to mobile development. I am familiar with c#.net so i started working on `xamarin`. As far as now i am able to add 2 charts in it. Problems i am facing are as follows

1. While rotating device the chart is fixed, i.e. i can't scroll (see bellow image)

[image]

In above image i can see the first chart but can't see the second chart full, as scroll is not working. How to enable scroll ?

1. While on screen horizontal or vertical if I slide the chart, the axis moves automatically, which they should not do as i have set them to a fixed values. See the bellow image

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the above images when i slide the chart also does causing the axis to increase. I want to stop it.

Bellow is my code in which i have fixed my axis `maximum` and `minimum` values

```
plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, Maximum = 10, Minimum = 0 });
plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, Maximum = 10, Minimum = 0 });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable scrolling try using a `ScrollViewer` surrounding your plots:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
    <oxy:PlotView .../>
    <oxy:PlotView .../>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And for your axis issue, if you want your plot axes to be fixed even when zooming, you have to use `AbsoluteMaximum` and `AbsoluteMinimum` properties on `Axis`:

```
plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis()
{
    Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
    AbsoluteMaximum = 10,
    AbsoluteMinimum = 0,
});
```